# Read CSV in R and filter columns by name

Tags: r, csv, readr

Let's say I have a CSV with dozens or hundreds of columns and I want to pull in just about 2 or 3 columns. I know about the `colClasses` solution as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/reading-only-two-out-of-three-columns-with-read-csv) but the code gets very unreadable.

I want something like `usecols` from [pandas' `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Loading everything and just selecting afterwards is not a solution (the file is super big, it doesn't fit in memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use package `data.table` and then with `fread()` specify columns to keep/drop by arguments `select`or `drop`. From `?fread`

> select    Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest.
>
> drop   Vector of column names or numbers to drop, keep the rest.

Best!

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use package `sqldf`. If you know SQL, it is possible to read in large files filtering only the parts you want.

I will use built-in dataset `iris` to make the example reproducible, saving it to disk first.

```
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Now the problem.
Argument `row.names` is like in the `write.csv` instruction.
Note the backticks around `Sepal.Length`. This is due to the dot character in the column name.

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "select `Sepal.Length`, Species from file"
sub_iris <- read.csv.sql("iris.csv", sql = sql, row.names = FALSE)

head(sub_iris)
#  Sepal.Length  Species
#1          5.1 "setosa"
#2          4.9 "setosa"
#3          4.7 "setosa"
#4          4.6 "setosa"
#5          5.0 "setosa"
#6          5.4 "setosa"
```

And final clean up.

```
unlink("iris.csv")
```