# Selecting specific columns to read with dbWriteTable from RSQLite package

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I woud like to transform a very big `csv` file into a `sqlite` file. I see that I can do it via `dbWriteTable` from `RSQLite` R package. However, I would like to select a specific subset of columns I am interested to, in order to decrease memory space and future computational time. Does somebody knows how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't/don't want to just import the CSV file directly into SQLite?  There are a number of ways to do this.

Comment: Why you just select the columns you want to transform by using `filter` o the equivalent `data.frame` or `data.table` sintax? You can even just read your desired columns to save from `csv`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611277/read-csv-in-r-and-filter-columns-by-name/54611305#54611305

Comment: I can import the all CSV file and then remove columns I don't need, but I was wondering why don't do it immediately  just by not selecting them.

Comment: Then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611277/read-csv-in-r-and-filter-columns-by-name/54611305#54611305